# Bound on the success probability of binomial trial

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim Binomial(n, p)$. If $p$ is bounded s.t. $p_{\text{min}} \le p \le 1/2$, is there a bound in the error in empirical probability compared to true probability? The empirical probability $\bar{p} = n_{\text{success}} / n$.

What I'm trying to find is a theorem of the form:

> If $p_{\text{min}} \le p \le 1/2$, then $|\bar{p} - p| \le radius$ with high probability.

if one exists.

Edit: Since I must work with finite number of iterations, normal approximation guaranteed by the CLT for large $n$ does not hold. As such, I modeled the expected error as a beta distribution instead.

Comment: From one point of view, the entire distribution of the error is given by the CLT.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the [Chernoff-Hoeffding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Additive_form_(absolute_error)), also [Hoeffding's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), the [DeMoivre-Laplace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) for an improved central limit theorem, or just the central limit theorem as gt6989b suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. My knowledge of Hoeffding bound is that it is meant to work for all bounded random variables, so it's looser than if we know what the random variable is (in this case, binomial). As for the CLT or DeMoivre-Laplace theorem, they only guarantee asymptotic convergence of the error to normal distribution. The question I have is whether there is an error bound for finite $n$ that is specific to binomial distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using the "generic [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound)." Write $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ as the sum of $n$ iid Bernoulli variables $\text{Ber}(p)$, so that the empirical probability is the average $\frac{X}{n}$. [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) applied to $e^{tX}$ gives that for $t \ge 0$ we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \ge a \right) = \mathbb{P}(e^{tX} \ge e^{tna}) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})}{e^{tna}}.$$

which gives

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \ge a \right) \le \inf_{t \ge 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})}{e^{tna}}.$$

We now compute this infimum. We have $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{tX_1})^n = \left( p e^t + (1 - p) \right)^n$ so taking the logarithmic derivative of the bound gives

$$\frac{d}{dt} \log \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})}{e^{tna}} = n \left( \frac{pe^t}{pe^t + (1 - p)} - a \right).$$

Setting this equal to zero and solving for $e^t$ gives $e^t = \frac{a(1-p)}{p(1-a)}$, which guarantees that $t \ge 0$ as long as $a \ge p$, and substituting this back in gives that if $a \ge p$ then

$$\boxed{ \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \ge a \right) \le \exp \left(- n KL(a, p) \right) }$$

where

$$\begin{align*} KL(a, p) &= - \log \left( a \frac{(1-p)}{1-a} + (1-p) \right) + a \log \frac{a(1-p)}{p(1-a)} \\
 &= a \log \frac{a}{p} + (1 - a) \log \frac{1-a}{1-p} \end{align*}$$

is the **rate function**; this is an example of a [large deviation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory), I guess it is called the [Chernoff-Hoeffding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Additive_form_(absolute_error)), and $KL$ is the [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between $\text{Ber}(a)$ and $\text{Ber}(p)$. We have $KL(a, p) \ge 0$ with equality iff $a = p$ as expected, so that when $a > p$ this tells us that the probability that the empirical probability exceeds the true probability by a fixed positive constant decays exponentially in $n$. Morever, [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)) tells us that this exponent $KL(a, p)$ is asymptotically optimal in the sense that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \ge a \right)}{n} = - KL(a, p)$.

We can get a bound on $\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \le a \right)$ from this bound by considering $Y = n - X = \sum_{i=1}^n (1 - X_i)$ which is again a sum of $n$ iid Bernoulli random variables $\text{Ber}(1 - p)$. Then $\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \le a \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{Y}{n} \ge 1 - a \right)$, which gives that if $a \le p$ then

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{X}{n} \le a \right) \le \exp \left( - n KL(1-a, 1-p) \right) = \exp \left( - n KL(a, p) \right)$$

from which we conclude that

$$\boxed{ \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{X}{n} - p \right| < \varepsilon \right) \ge 1 - \exp \left( - n KL(p + \varepsilon, p) \right) - \exp \left( - n KL(p - \varepsilon, p) \right) }.$$

This can be massaged into various other forms depending on what you need. For example if you want $\varepsilon = O \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)$ then you'd want to investigate the first few terms of the Taylor series of $KL(p \pm \varepsilon, p)$ which will recover a CLT / Hoeffding-type bound.

Comment: This is what I needed and definitely more rigorous than my other attempts. I'll be studying this, thanks.

Comment: It is nice. A question about the notation: $KL(a, p)$ and $\mathrm{KL}(a, p)$, which one is preferred?

Comment: I don't know. The wikipedia article uses $D_{\text{KL}}$ which personally I find clunky.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I prefer to $\mathrm{KL}$. Similarly, for cyclic sum, we should use $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ rather than $\sum\limits_{cyc}$.