Estimation of Sum of Binomial Coefficients that doesn't Start from Zero
I am having some trouble showing the following estimation:

Let $\mu \in (0, 1)$ be an absolute constant. There exists an absolute constant $\eta \in (0, 1)$ small enough such that the number of subsets of $\{ 1, \cdots, N \}$ with cardinality at least $(1 - 4\eta^2) N$ is at most $\mu^{-N/4}$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt is the following:
We know this is equivalent to showing the estimation for sum of binomial coefficients. That is, we want to find $\eta \in (0, 1)$ small enough such that
$$ 
\sum_{j = (1 - 4\eta^2)N} ^N \binom{N}{j} \leq \mu^{-N/4}.
$$
In particular, this is equivalent to saying finding a portion size (absolute constant) $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ big enough such that
$$
\sum_{j = \alpha N} ^N \binom{N}{j} \leq \mu^{-N/4}.
$$
We may roughly write the sum as
$$
\sum_{j = 0} ^N \binom{N}{j} - \sum_{j = 0} ^{\alpha N} \binom{N}{j}.
$$
According to the classical inequality on sum of binomials, we may upper bound the first term above by $\left( \frac{eN}{N} \right)^N = e^N$ and lower the second term above by $\binom{N}{\alpha N}$. In particular, we can write the estimation
$$
\sum_{j = 0} ^N \binom{N}{j} - \sum_{j = 0} ^{\alpha N} \binom{N}{j} \leq e^N - \binom{N}{\alpha N}.
$$
Thus now we need to show
$$
e^N - \binom{N}{\alpha N} \leq \mu^{-N/4}
$$
for all $N$. I am stuck at this step. Is there an easy way to estimate what the absolute constant $\alpha$ is supposed to be here?

This can be done using the Chernoff bound: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549070/inequality-proof-without-stirlings-formula-involving-binary-entropy/4552240#4552240

$$\binom{N}{\alpha N} \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi \alpha (1 - \alpha )N} }}\left( {(1 - \alpha )^{1 - \alpha } \alpha ^\alpha  } \right)^{ - N} $$
